# PostgreSQL database backup is empty - what's wrong?

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, cron, backup

I want to configure backup of the Alfresco database (PostgreSQL rdbms).

For that I have a script like this:

psql-create-backup:

```
#!/bin/sh
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -Fc -Z9 -c -f /home/bykovan/alfresco-data-backup/"`date +%d-%m-%Y`".alfresco.backup alfresco
```

I saved it in `/home/bykovan` and gave rights to execute:

```
[bykovan@docflow ~]$ sudo chmod 711 psql-create-backup
```

Then I added the job to cron:

```
[bykovan@docflow ~]$ sudo crontab -e
...

0 0 * * * /home/bykovan/psql-create-backup
```

In the `pg_hba.conf` I added this line `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`:

```
[bykovan@docflow ~]$ sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf

-- SKIPPED --


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host     all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host     all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident

host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16            md5
-- VISUAL BLOCK --
```

Backups are empty:

```
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-data-backup]$ ls -lh

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 feb 18 00:00 18-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 feb 19 00:00 19-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 feb 20 00:00 20-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 feb 21 00:00 21-02-2017.alfresco.backup
```

---

In the `pg_hba.conf` I added this lines:

```
host    all  all       ::1/128      md5
host    all  postgres  127.0.0.1/32 trust
```

Then restart service:

```
[bykovan@docflow ~]$ sudo service postgresql-9.5 stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  postgresql-9.5.service
[bykovan@docflow ~]$ sudo service postgresql-9.5 start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  postgresql-9.5.service
```

Then ran command direct in the prompt (*I was prompted for the password*) and saw the following:

```
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-data-backup]$ ls -lh

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 feb 17 18:39 17-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 feb 18 00:00 18-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 feb 19 00:00 19-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 feb 20 00:00 20-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 feb 21 19:41 21-02-2017.alfresco.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 667K feb 22 07:04 22-02-2017.alfresco.backup
```

But running the task via cron gave me the empty files...

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: what happen if you run the command direct in the prompt? run ok?

Comment: Can you give the full path to `pg_dump` from where it is installed in `crontab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the password in the script, it now looks like this:

```
PGPASSWORD="some_password" pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -Fc -Z9 -c -f /home/bykovan/alfresco-data-backup/"`date +%d-%m-%Y`".alfresco.backup alfresco
```

Now everything is Ok.

Comment: You might want to use a .pgpass file https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html